# python checking strings in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to iterate through a list checking every string in the list for a character.

```
test = [str(i) for i in range(100)]

for i in test:
    if '0' or '4' or '6' or '8' in str(i):
        test.remove(i)
```

I thought this would be fine but, the list is this after:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```

Where the '2' is removed but, the '41' is not?  I've noticed its only even numbers but, don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems. First, this `if` statement is always taken.

```
if '0' or '4' or '6' or '8' in str(i):
```

Because the string `0` is a non-zero-length string, and is therefore `True`. `0` or `4` is `0` and therefore `True`. The rest of the statement doesn't matter.

I expect you actually wanted to test whether *each* of those digits was in the string representation of the integer. As you have it written now, you are only testing whether `8` is in the string, and that's not even getting tested because the expression evaluates to `True` before it even gets there. Something like this would work:

```
if any(x in i for x in '0468'):
```

By the way, `str(i)` is superfluous because your list is already a list of strings.

The other problem is that you are deleting items from the list you are iterating over. So, here's what happens:

- The first item, `0`, is removed, because your `if` statement is always taken.
- The second item, `1`, becomes the first item, because you removed `0`.
- The `for` loop goes on to the second item, which is now `2`.

In other words, because you deleted `0`, `1` is never tested. Thus, every other item (all the even numbers) are removed.

The easiest way to avoid this in your code is to iterate over a copy of the list:

```
for i in test[:]:
```

Answer (score 11):

There are two issues with your code.  The first is that you are modifying the list while iterating over it.  The second is that you are using the `or` operator in the wrong way – the condition in the `if` statement will always be `True`.

Here's a fixed version:

```
test = [i for i in range(100) if set("0468").isdisjoint(str(i))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
(Pdb) i=2
(Pdb) i='2'
(Pdb) '0' or 'beer' in str(i)
'0'
(Pdb) bool('0')
True
```

Do you see why `'0' or '4' or '6' or '8' in str(i)` is not always a boolean value?

Now, consider what you're removing:

```
>>> l=[str(i) for i in range(10)]
>>> for i in l:
...   print i
...   print l
...   l.remove(i)
... 
0
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
2
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
4
['1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
6
['1', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
8
['1', '3', '5', '7', '8', '9']
```

As you remove elements in-place while you're iterating over the list, you're shortening the list and skipping each next value.

[Sven has the right pythonic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055881/418413), but I felt a more lengthy explanation might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute something like `'0' or '4'`, the `or` operator will verify if the first parameter (`'0'`) is false-ish and, if it is not false, it returns the first value. Since `'0'` is not false (it is a non-empty string, which yields `True` when used as boolean), it will return the first value and the following one will not even be considered:

```
>>> '0' or '4'
'0'
```

If you repeat it, you will get the same result:

```
>>> '0' or '4' or '6' or '8'
'0'
```

Also, the `in` operator has greater precedence, so it will be executed before each `or`:

> > > '0' or '4' or '6' or '8' in '88'
> > >          '0'

What you want to do in your condition is to verify if any of the values is in the result:

```
>>> '0' in str(i) or '4' in str(i) or '6' in str(i) or '8' in str(i)
True
>>> i = 17
>>> '0' in str(i) or '4' in str(i) or '6' in str(i) or '8' in str(i)
False
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but it is the best translation of your intentions.

So, what would be an elegant solution? As sugested by @sven, you can create a set ([more about it](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)) of the sought chars:

```
>>> sought = set("0468")
>>> sought
set(['0', '8', '4', '6'])
```

and then create a set of the digits in your number:

```
>>> i = 16
>>> set(str(i))
set(['1', '6'])
```

Now, just see if [they are disjoint](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint):

```
>>> i = 16
>>> sought.isdisjoint(set(str(i)))
False
>>> i = 17
>>> sought.isdisjoint(set(str(i)))
True
```

In this case, if the set are *not* disjoint, then you want to preserve it:

```
>>> found = []
>>> for i in range(100):
...     if sought.isdisjoint(set(str(i))):
...         found.append(i)
... 
>>> found
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 59, 71, 72, 73, 75, 77, 79, 91, 92, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```

Most of the time, every time you get yourself creating a `for` loop for filtering an iterator, what you really want is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [i for i in range(100) if sought.isdisjoint(set(str(i)))]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 59, 71, 72, 73, 75, 77, 79, 91, 92, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```

Or, using a clumsier but more novice-friendly construct:

```
>>> [i for i in range(100) if not ( '0' in str(i) or '4' in str(i) or '6' in str(i) or '8' in str(i) )]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 59, 71, 72, 73, 75, 77, 79, 91, 92, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here with the line:

```
if '0' or '4' or '6' or '8' in str(i):
```

It is incorrect. It would be better to write it so:

```
if any(x in i for x in '0468'):
```

The second problem (as mentioned Sven) is that you modify the list while iterating over it.

The best solution is:

```
[i for i in test if not any(x in i for x in '0468')]
```

Comment: You are still modifying `test` while iterating over it.

Comment: You are right, I just tried to keep closer to the question. I will fix my answer

Comment: Thank you, but even if you would, it would be fair :)

Answer (score 0):

```
itms = ['0','4','6','8']
test = [str(i) for i in range(100) if not  any([x in str(i) for x in itms])]
```

maybe .... thats untested but i think it will work